# Setup Active Directory witin a existing infrastructure using static bind server

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, bind

I would like to get an advice how to fix the following situation.

My current infrastructure has 30+ linux boxes and 5 windows servers.
I use bind dns master+2xslave with a non dynamic zone setup.

linux boxes are managed with an orcestration tool and login is done using ssh keys.  Windows machines are in workgroup because we have only 5 of them and an AD was not needed.

Now the situation has changed and in a while there will be a massive addon for the windows servers, and im tinkering how to implement a Active directory for management and user authentication.

i came out with the following idea, but maybe someone can give me a better solution.

My current bind zone name is "example.local" and i need to keep it on the linux box.

I thought to install AD with an dns zone name "win.example.local" and configure the dns forwarder for "example.local" to my bind, and add a forward zone on the bind server to forward request for "win.example.local" to the windows box.

The other idea was to install AD as "example.local" manually add the records from existing bind to it and reconfigure the clients to use it as a new dns server.

thanks!

Comment: Forwarding the requests sounds good, but keep in mind to not using .local as TLD. Just install the Windows AD as (eg.) ad.company.tld

Answer (score 3):

I would configure the domain in parallel. (As JohannesM's mention, you better use a real domain for that)

The only detail your post miss is for the DHCP. Do you need it for linux computer, or you can use it for your windows domain's computer ?

I ask as you can set manually the DNS in some computer that need to be in the Windows domain (or vice versa depending on the park you manage). I would not point everyone to one DNS. From your example I would configure the 5 computers to use the windows DNS and other computers to use your bind server.

After that you create a conditional forward for your example.local's zone in the windows's dns server and the forward zone in your bind server to redirect to your windows dns's server.

Answer (score 1):

1. Setup Active Directory domain as subdomain of your bind zone with own AD integrated DNS servers to host it.
2. Delegate Active Directory subdomain to AD integrated DNS servers.
3. Setup on AD integrated DNS servers request forwarding to bind server
4. If you use DHCP for Windows hosts - set up as a DNS AD integrated servers, for secure updates work.
5. Move you reverse DNS zone to AD integrated servers if you plan to use MS DHCP otherwise you can leave as is.

What you get:

- Windows PC will receive all advantages of work with AD integrated DNS
- Resolution of names would work equally well across any of your DNS
  servers
- External name resolution will done by  bind (it is objectively able to do it better)

Comment: I second that. While [***it is possible***](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316373.aspx) to have a static DNS zone configured to be used for Active Directory's name resolution, it is considerably more hassle and has a number of drawbacks. Just using a subdomain with AD DNS servers and delegating it using NS RRs in your BIND zone is the cleanest solution.